# Xamarin.Forms ListView - Refresh sometimes temporarily hides images

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in my application. Sometimes (both on Android and iOS) a pull to refresh will temporarily "hide" some of the images. These images will almost always return when next refreshed.

Here is the code that sets the image source (have tried without Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread)

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    //Set Image value for list item
    listItem.Image = ImageSource.FromResource(String.Format("AppName.FolderName.{0}.png", returnedItem.Description.Replace(" ", "")));
});
```

Here is the code in the UI for the listview:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="True" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="ShowItem">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,25,0,25" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                     <Image HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" Source="{Binding Path=Image}" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                     <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}" FontSize="19" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                     <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                         <Label Text="{Binding Path=Amount}" FontSize="20" TextColor="#b3b3b3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource MediumFont}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Value}" FontSize="14" TextColor="#b3b3b3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource LightFont}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                     </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Unfortunately I can't show any screenshots of the app as my employer does not allow. I have however made 2 separate apps in the last 6 months, both with listviews containing images and the issue occurs on both apps (on both platforms).  The other app contains very similar code for the listview.

Note: the images are stored in a folder in the main project, and are configured to have a build action of "embedded resource" (as instructed via Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images)).

Has anybody had this issue before or can anyone please offer a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I have changed the way I store the images by using the resources folder (drawable) for Android and Asset Catalog for Apple.
I then modified my code to read:

`listItem.Image = ImageSource.FromFile(String.Format(${returnedItem.Description.Replace(" ", "")}.png"));`